# Itunesconnect App Preview Video

Tags: ios

I have tried many times to upload App Preview video.
But each time I failed.
Please recommend me best tool to convert my video to availble and how to.
Thanks

Comment: If you are using a mac you can record video straight from the QuickTime app when your device is plugged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `Safari` to upload your video.

I use `QuickTime Player` to record the screen of my app.

In `QuickTime Player` you can record in portrait and landscape, but you cannot rotate your screen during the record.

Open `QuickTime Player > File > New Movie Recording` (then select your device for camera and microfone).

Sample of record screen:

[image: Sample]

Answer (score 1):

Apple App Preview Video Guidelines
As you can imagine, Apple wants to generate a similar Look & Feel for all videos. Therefore they released some guidelines, which you should mind when creating a preview video.

15-30 seconds length

Maximum file size of 500 mb

.mov, .m4v, .mp4 format

Only use screen capture

No (very less) copy – due to the reason that you can’t internationalize your video and only upload it once in one language

Don’t overlay animated hands, you can use touch hotspots if really necessary
For games: Show more gameplay scenes than cutscenes

You can use voice over – but mind the internationalization part – Apple recommends to only use a very limited and professional voice over if you have to

Your preview video should only contain content for which you have the full rights (don’t show you app streaming content from an iTunes Playlist or a YouTube video)

**App Preview Video Format**

Now the most important part – which format or size should your video have. As you have already read in my screenshot size article it can be quite frustrating creating a lot screenshots in different sizes.

Apple recommends you to use the following app preview resolutions (this is already a summary, that you have to create the least amount of different video versions):

iPhone 5+ iPhone 6 Plus: 1920 x 1080

iPhone 6: 1334 x 750

iPad: 1200 x 900